# Spring Bean Factory Configuration passing input parameter

Tags: spring

I'm trying to create a BeanFactory called TaskBeanFactory that I can Autowire into another prototype class that's running on a thread. I want a different instance of a bean returned by the Factory based on a taskName that i want to pass into it but when i start the application i get a null pointer exception because the taskName is null. I had a look at [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean) but i'm confused about how I should configure the Factory and then pass in the taskName.

The Factory:

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Data
    @Component
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class TaskBeanFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<GenericTask>{

        private TaskNameEnum taskName;

        public TaskBeanFactory(TaskNameEnum taskName) {     
            setSingleton(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return GenericTask.class;
        }

        @Override
        protected GenericTask createInstance() throws Exception {
            switch (taskName) {
                case FILE_OPERATION:
                    return new FileTask();
                case DATA_OPERATION:            
                    return new DataTask();          
                default:
                    return new GenericTask();
            }
        }

    }
```

The classes used by the Factory:

```
@Data
    public class GenericTask {

        private String idTask;

        public void executeTask(Work work) {};
    }



 @Component
    @Scope(value="prototype")
    public class FileTask extends GenericTask {

        @Override
        public void executeTask(Work work) {        
            //some processing
        }
    }

@Component
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class DataTask extends GenericTask {

    @Override
    public void executeTask(Work work) {        
        //some processing
    }
}
```

and the thread that's calling the Factory:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private TaskBeanFactory taskBeanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    @Override
    public void run() {

            //iterate a Map of taskIds from the dataService

            taskBeanFactory.setTaskName(TaskNameEnum.valueOf(taskEntry.getKey()));
            GenericTask genericTask = taskBeanFactory.getObject();

            //expecting genericTask to be of Type FileTask if called with one Key 
            //or of Type DataTask if called with another
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not how the Spring `FactoryBean` works. Just write a factory as you normally would.

Comment: Can you be specific and give me an example?